# HTTP Post from Gradle task - Groovy

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am making `Http Post` call using the plugin `io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin`. Below is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
     id "io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin" version "0.1.1"
}

import groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder

task makeRESTCall () {
onlyIf {
    !dependencyList.empty
}
doFirst {
    println dependencyList
    def http = HttpBuilder.configure {
        request.uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
        request.contentType = 'application/json'
        request.uri.path = '/api/v1/fosscomponents/bulkvalidate'
    }
    http.post {
        request.body=dependencyList
        response.success {
            println "Success"
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my `dependencyList` parameter that am sending in `request.body`

```
[

{
    "groupId":"org.hibernate",
    "artifactId":"hibernate-validator",
    "version":"5.3.6.Final"
}, 
{
    "groupId":"org.projectlombok",
    "artifactId":"lombok",
    "version":"1.16.22"
}, 
{
    "groupId":"io.springfox",
    "artifactId":"springfox-swagger-ui",
    "version":"2.8.0"
}
]
```

My java code in my backend API (written in Spring Boot) just prints in this format

```
incomingLists.stream().forEach(
            obj -> System.out.println(obj.getGroupId()+" **** "+obj.getArtifactId()+" **** "+obj.getVersion())
        );
```

When i hit this API from my postman, the response is correct- see below print from the code

```
org.hibernate **** hibernate-validator **** 5.3.6.Final
org.projectlombok **** lombok **** 1.16.22
```

whereas when i hit the same API from my gradle task, my java code prints it this way..

```
null **** null **** null
null **** null **** null
```

Am not sure if am missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this !! the `request.body` as shown above is just sending the `dependencyList` as a list object itself and not as a `String` as expected by the API.

so i changed it to below way and it worked as expected :)

```
http.post {
        request.body=dependencyList.toString()
        response.success {
            println "Success"
        }
 }
```